# file association with large amount of users

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I am sorry if this is a dumb question I have the following code

```
function trc_upload_file() {

    $form['trc_upload_form'] = array(
        '#type'         =>  'managed_file',
        '#title'        =>  'Upload File',
        '#descripion'   =>  'Uplaod files',     
    );

    $form['#submit'][] = 'trc_upload_file_submit';
    return $form;       
}

function trc_upload_file_submit($form, &$form_state) {

    $file = file_load($form_state['values']['trc_upload_form']);    
    $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
    file_save($file);

    /*file_usage_add($file, 'trc_upload_page', 'user', $account->uid);*/

    drupal_set_message(t('You Uploaded Successfully!'));

}
```

this is working fine 
how to use file_usage_add() function, can i use it for user_roles instead individual users.

Comment: Have you tried `file_usage_add($file, 'myModule', 'role', $roleID)` ? Posting as a comment because I haven't verified it works.

Comment: @KerrM: You should post that as the answer, it'll work fine like that. The `type` is not related to anything as such it's just an identifying string that can be used in conjunction with `file_usage_delete` to target the correct usage entry later on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Clive has confirmed, this should work:

`file_usage_add($file, 'trc_upload_page', 'role', $roleID);`

Let us know how you get on,